# Silverstripe - load page via ajax which includes CSS/JS

Tags: ajax, content-management-system, silverstripe

in a silverstripe project I´m loading whole pages via ajax. Therefore I added to the Page-Contoller following function:

```
public function ajax(){
    return $this->renderWith('MyTemplate');
}
```

This works fine so far and I get the page rendered as I want when browsing to mysite.com/mypage/ajax. The only Problem are the included JS/CSS Files in the template "MyTemplate":

```
<% require javascript(my.js) %>
<% require css(my.css) %>
```

The css/js does not show up in the source code - somehow it is not included, although it is part of the template "MyTemplate".

So is there a way to add the css/js in a cool way with silverstripe methods?

I tried this:

```
public function ajax(){
    Requirements::css("my.js");
    return $this->renderWith('ProjectPage');
}
```

but no success so far.
Many thanks,
Florian

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the following javascript file into your site, depending on silverstripe version:

SS3 - /framework/javascript/jquery-ondemand/jquery.ondemand.js

OR

SS2.4 -/sapphire/javascript/core/jquery.ondemand.js

As far as I understand; when you make an ajax request, any new css or javascript requirements are added into the the request header. Then when the request is successful, ondemand.js pulls those scripts into the document for you, if they are not already there.

Comment: hi thank you! where do I have to add the script? I added it now in the main Page.ss: <% require javascript(framework/javascript/jquery-ondemand/jquery.ondemand.js) %>
But somehow nothing changes...

Comment: maybe it does not work. here in the section Ideas/Problems  (http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/requirements) they mention to just include all scripts needed in the page which is loaded before the ajax call.